# Processing exported project requires java runtime enviroment when I already have one

Tags: java, processing

I am working on a project on Processing and when I export the project and try to run it, it says that Java Runtime Enviroment is required. I have JRE 1.8.0_121 which is newer than the required one so i guess it shouldn't be problematic. I installed JDK but nothing changed. The project runs only when I export the project embedded for windows 64-bit (and then it doesn't let me delete it because some java processes appear). I have also tried updating the system variables JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME.
 Any help and ideas will be appreciated ^^

Comment: Step 1: Tell us how you're running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems just disappeared when I reinstalled Processing.

Answer (score 0):

The `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` variables don't matter in this case.

The only thing that matters is your `PATH` variable.

So you need to check what's on your PATH.

- What happens when you type `java -version` in a command prompt?
- What is currently on your path? Watch out for other versions of Java that have already been added!

If you still can't get it working, try running the executable from the command prompt so you can see exactly what error you're getting.

You might also try uninstalling (make sure you delete the settings directories as well) and reinstalling Processing.

Comment: when I type `java -version`, it appears this newer than the required one.  But I don't know what is it with this PATH variable, can you give a bit more detail about it?

Comment: @nikifaets Have you tried Googling the PATH variable? There are a ton of tutorials out there that show you how to set it. What happens when you run the executable from the command prompt?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
This is with java -version on command prompt, and when i execute it there, the same problem appears  with JRE

Comment: @nikifaets Can you be more specific than saying the same problem appears? What is the exact error message?

Comment: "This application requires a Java Runtime Enviroment 1.8.0_74"

Comment: @nikifaets That's weird. What happens when you type `javac -version` from the command prompt? Notice the c at the end of java in that command.

Comment: "javac is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file "

Comment: @nikifaets Try installing the JDK and adding it to your path?

Comment: @nikifaets If you had already done that, you wouldn't get the message saying that `javac` is not recognized.

Comment: I did it after after I said it is not recognised, sorry about the mistyping

Comment: @nikifaets Hmmm then I'm running out of ideas. Maybe try uninstalling Processing (make sure you also delete all of the settings files) and reinstalling it? Can you post your code, or a link to your application?

Comment: I just reinstalled Processing and now it runs perfectly. I have no idea what was the problem, but anyways thank you very much for helping me, really apreciated!